# MVC Razor line cut prevent and null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have got this line in my razor mvc view:

```
< div class="fileContainer @(Model.FileGroup.Files.Count > 5 ? " scroll" : "" )"
```

every time I save it cuts and removes to

```
< div class="fileContainer @(Model.FileGroup.Files.Count > 5 ? " scroll" 
"" )">
```

How can I fix this without doing a variable in top @{}

My second question is how can I fix nested null values in a view, lets say I got `Model.FileGroup.Files` and `Model.FileGroup` is null and I am reading `Model.FileGroup`. Files everything crash.

I know a model should not be null, but can I ignore a case like this in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'single quotes' to wrap the entire `class` attribute; else you are confusing the parser with the nested quotes. I would still prefer to see this markup simplified by using a variable, but you asked for a solution without.

Normally, you shouldn't ask two unrelated questions in the same StackOverflow post, but since I'm here anyway; let's answer the `null` problem. There are two solutions, and you might use a combination of these.

1. If you have a valid reason for it to be null and/or you can't change that, you can use `@if` blocks, so something like:

```
@if (Model.FileGroup != null) {
        //do stuff with this property
} else {
     //output a "no files" message? 
}
```

2. It's usually best to ensure that `null` can't happen. Usually this is the job of the Model / ViewModel's constructor.

```
public class SomeClass {
   public SomeClass() {
       //prevent nulls
       FileGroup = new FileGroup();
       AwesomeList = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    public FileGroup FileGroup { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> AwesomeList { get; private set; }
}
```